# Google Map OnClick, How to Programmatically get clicked point information and add a pushPin

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am new to Google Maps programming, and I want to :

- add a pushpin onclick
- get the clicked point location

in addition, I want to code this in javascript(&jquery)

In fact, here is an example of what I mean

http://www.gorissen.info/Pierre/maps/googleMapLocation.php

so, can anyone provide me with information about how I can code it?
Kind regards!

Comment: What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: I have tried the following codes and I dont know how to add a pushPin

    var long;
    var lat;
    GEvent.addListener(map,"click", function(overlay,latlng) {
      long = latlng.lng();
      lat = latlng.lat();
    });

Answer (score 3):

GEvent is Maps API 2 which is deprecated. You should be using Maps API 3 instead (especially if you're starting out 'new' and not having to maintain an old API 2 site).  And when you do, something like this should work:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: event.latLng,
        map: map
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much DUNCAN for this answer, but it seems like your code doesn't add a push to the location. Do You Have an idea ?